# What does calling jQuery with a function do?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I see people doing this:

```
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

What does calling jQuery with a function do?

Comment: see http://api.jquery.com/ready/ or http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: Is it that hard to look at the documentation for the jQuery function? http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery3

Comment: @cookiemonster Believe it or not I was looking at the jquery documentation. I must have missed it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/ready/)

The .ready() method is typically used with an anonymous function:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

Which is equivalent to calling:

```
$(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
});
```

This Specifies a function to execute when the [DOM](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CBoQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model&ei=9VCiU9fbINO9ugS124C4CQ&usg=AFQjCNFlNlOo-UNooWntVi9WsqXpbZO_QA&bvm=bv.69411363,d.c2E) is fully loaded.